# Ssh terminal emulation for windows

Tags: windows, ssh, xserver

is there a good and comfortable ssh terminal emulation for Windows?
I want to connect to a ubuntu server and work remotely like i can do 
with ssh -Y . I am currently using cygwin for this, but it takes up a 
lot of space and it lacks some features that would be nice.

tl,dr:
I am looking for a terminal client for windows, that
- does Ssh with Xserver - grafical
- copies files ( works as a ssh client like winssh )
- basically behaves as if i sat before the (ubuntu) computer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For SSH you can use putty. To copy files there's WinSCP. To run X programs there's any number of X servers for Windows, like Xming or Exceed. You might also want to use VNC to connect to an existing X session (you need to run a VNC server on your Ubuntu computer and a VNC client on Windows). These are all very different and cannot replace one another.

Comment: i was looking for something like exceed or xming. do you know which one is better?

Comment: @tarrasch : I have used Exceed briefly and it's OK, cannot say much about Xming.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is VNC and not ssh.

http://www.tightvnc.com/

Answer (score 0):

Reading your requirements, you could consider running cygwin, that will give you the ability to run some Linux programs in Windows, including xterm. As a bonus, you can use bash instead of the normal windows shell.